# Invoke payments from server side

Tags: facebook, payment, subscriptions

I would like to know if there is a way for invoking payment facebook API, from server side, without user intervention. I.e. Once the user approves one payment, server side acts by itself, without regarding (and annoying) the user for approvals for subsecuent payments.

This could apply to services which its business is based on repetition, e.g. in a monthly basis or weekly basis.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I think the only way to do this is by susbcriptions, but it limits the usage of one or more services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible, I mean, if you payment method is Facebook credits then users will have to deal with payment gateway. On the other hand, if you have some business based on repetition then you will have to use Facebook subscriptions, as you said.

Perhaps you could perform something based on SOAP-WS, but I don't know if Facebook has services available for that.